# Use two connection strings depending a selection made on first form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

First let me give some background. when u start the app u get the first form login_frm that validates username and pass word with a mysql connection to mysql server after you logged in you get a mdi parent ( main_frm ) form and child forms that open with toolbar in parent

So, what I need is a way to use a combobox in login form with two values lets say "local" and "remote". If I select local the login and all forms after login must use the local connection string and same goes for remote.

I can always just use the remote connection string everywhere but interwebs in South Africa is not up to standard. It would be a mess to create two versions of the same app just to change the connection string.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: This is just a simple `if` statement.  If this is causing you problems you may want to read an introductory `c#` book.

Comment: The correct way to indicate that your question has been answered is to *accept* an answer. If Tore's answer is the one that solved your problem for you, please accept it. If you solved your problem in some other way, please *write an answer* and then (after the enforced delay) accept that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might misunderstand you question but it seems that you simply need an `if` to initialize your connection string based on the selected value of the combobox:

```
string connectionString;
if (selectedComboboxValue=="local")
  connectionString = "...";
else
  connectionString = "...";
```

The connection or connection string could then be "stored" in the model behind the page making it available for various forms. If you find you need more options, then maybe a dictionary with the different connection strings would be simpler.

Comment: Thanks i also carried the selected value over in a hidden text box to new forms and used that to determine local or remote thanks a lot buddy